# Experiencing problems with installing device drivers on Ubuntu VM.

Tags: virtualbox

I am new to Ubuntu and am currently working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I installed VirtualBox to create another Ubuntu VM. Initially I had problems with maximizing my Ubuntu VMscreen. I resolved the issue by installing the drivers. I rebooted the system and tried again, but the issue persists. Please excuse my layman terms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem caused by VirtualBox, not by Ubuntu. Your best shot might be to try the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

[Installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36500_01/E36502/html/qs-guest-additions.html)